# SC Marketing Cloud - mobile connect sms bit.ly link?

Tags: mobileconnect, sms

Is there anyway to automatically add and track bit.ly links to SMS messages sent from SFMC? Any other option for tracking click throughs from SMS messages?

Thanks,
M!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of tracking opens of an SMS  or clicks of URL from the SMS with mobile connect

You would however be able to track the bit.ly link by adding tracking strings to your shortened URL or track using Goggle Analytics

https://bitly.com/blog/bitly-vs-google-analytics